# Is there some library in python that can put texts on svg files?

Tags: library, python, svg

I was trying to write a program in python that can takes in a svg file as background and output the svg file with text on that background.

For example, if the input svg file is a circle, I want to output the svg file that has some texts inside that circle?

Is there any library to do that? Thanks a lot

Comment: SVG is just a subset of XML, so any XML parser/writer will do.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the famous Cairo library in Python (PyCairo) is able to do exactly that! https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/